# Block ssh with a reply message

Tags: ssh, firewall

I know that we can block incoming ssh using firewall rules from different ips but, is there a way to block any incoming ssh and send a reply like saying:
"You are not allowed to access this machine. Contact the admin for appropriate access....".

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [sf] or http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @Kenster how do I migrate this question from here to stackexchange?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did.

Open File

`vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Now Add or comment Banner in this file.And provide valid path Like

```
Banner /etc/banner
```

Now create file at given path

```
vim /etc/banner
```

And Add message here.Then restart ssh service.

```
/etc/init.d/sshd restart
```

Comment: The banner is sent to all clients, not just clients who aren't permitted to log in.